# Lock your computer when you walk away!

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle, computer-science

Well this is strange.

I forgot to lock my monitor when I walked away from my desk, at work, and one of my co-workers decided to have a little fun.

When I got back, I found this little C# console app code segment, sitting forefront on my machine.  I ran it a few times, but the results don't really tell me anything.

Does anyone else know what this could mean??

```
void Main()
{ 
  GetEwe();
  Console.WriteLine($"You have been given: {Ewe}");  
}

public enum Directions { Up, Down, Left, Right, Forward, Backward, Diagonally };
public Directions? Ewe;

public Directions GetEwe()
{
  Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
  do
  {
    Ewe = 
    (
      from direction in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Directions)).OfType<Directions>()
      //let u = Directions.Down     
      select direction
    ).ElementAt(rand.Next(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(Directions)).Length));
  }
  while (Ewe == Directions.Up);
  return Ewe.Value;  Around();
}

private void Around()
{
  Ewe = null;
}
```

Comment: With the new site icon and the introduction to the post, I thought I'm on Workplace.

Comment: Don't want to spoil, but shouldn't the line starting with // be like this:"//let Ewe = Directions.Down".

Comment: @Zikato - Nah, I wanted a bit of doubleplay on it to give at least a 4 second delay before people got it.  :P  (Also, without testing, it probably wouldn't have run, like that)

Comment: ...without being a comment, I mean. (Uncommenting the current version runs, even if it does nothing)

Comment: I thought maybe it was the first stab at a Rick-Rolling app...   :p

Comment: Nice to see someone making good use of the new language features in C# 6.0

Comment: Wait! You ran untrusted code even though you didn't know what it did, on your machine!?

Comment: @SnakeDoc We've [been through this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/lock-your-computer-when-you-walk-away?noredirect=1#comment98693_32909)... ;P

Comment: @TomášZato I actually I was on Workplace until I saw your comment.

Comment: @SnakeDoc It's obvious that it doesn't do anything bad, (no undefined behaviour, no file I/O, etc.) but it's not obvious what it *does* do.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I guess this is

> A [rickroll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLzxrzFCyOs)

Because

> This code is **never going to give you** (Ewe) **up**, because the loop will
>  assign a random direction to ewe as long as it is up
>  It is **never going to let you** (u) **down**, because the line`//let u = Directions.Down` is just a comment.
>  Since the return statement happens before calling `Around()`, it is obviously **never going to run around**.
>  **And**, because the method `Around()` is never called, it is also never going to "**desert you**", because it will never assign a null-value to Ewe.

Comment: For the fun of it you might want to put the link to the youtube video instead of your guess...you know, so people understand it better, not for any other reason :)

Comment: Wow - you know the rules, and so do I

Comment: @Marius Would love to, but I am in Germany and pretty much every youtube video of Rick Astley is blocked here, so I can't even search for them...

Comment: @JonathanAllan. Is there a rule against this? Since it's the actual answer why isn't it allowed?

Comment: @sandbo00. Huh? That's strange. What did he do wrong to get banned?

Comment: It *is* allowed - just second line of [the lyrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgLq6d_w4e4) :p

Comment: @Marius He did nothing, but the [GEMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEMA_%28German_organization%29) blocks pretty much every music video on youtube.

Comment: I think the important thing here is that all that happened was a rickroll. That C# code could've been really harmful; and I quote "*I ran it a few times*"

Comment: @warspyking Remember that we are on puzzling here, so I don't think that this background story actually happened ;-)

Comment: @sandbo00 Remember we are on puzzling here, so my comment contributed to the storyline itself ;-)

Comment: Well done for the perfect reasoning, sandbo00 =D

Comment: @warspyking I (the fictional me) trust my coworkers enough to know that they wouldn't do anything too harmful as a prank. :P

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Alright, just verifying. The situation you described could've been vary dangerous

Comment: But even if it doesn't let Ewe down on purpose it still could via the RNG. Rick Astley is a tricky one.

Comment: But at that point, it would give you down, not let you :P

Comment: Well, you could always `return Directions.Right; Around();`

Comment: Looks like is friday and no much to do for the rest of day, I wouldnt never solve it but was very funny

Comment: @saluce I find part of that change amusing, because it makes it slightly less obvious. :)

Comment: @saluce `Ewe.spin(this, Directions.Right) {Baby();} Math.Round(Directions.Right); struct Baby {}; Math.Round(Math.Round(Math.Round(Directions.Right)));`

Comment: (And because nobody will ever get it, some other languages have constructs called records. structs are like records)

Comment: @immibis it's okay, I got it ;)

Comment: @sandbo00 No Rick Astley?! That's horrible! :)

Comment: I'm so mad I opened this up