# Give me the name of the song

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> not sure if you like this
>   expecting to end with a kiss?
>
> video? You saw it.
>   even shared it a bit?
>
> ranting on the web somewhere
>   going to give you a little scare
>
> once it was a love song
>   now? Just a click gone wrong
>
> not adding this verse as a prank
>   actually I did, I'll be frank.
>
> give you a hint? I'm very picky
>   I tell you it's not sung by Martin, Ricky
>
> very confused about it right now?
>   explanation is in here, somehow.
>
> young people know it.
>   old ones at one point enjoyed it.
>
> unable to find something wrong
>   unless you try sing along.
>   please find the name of the song.

Comment: This question sounds like an attempt of rickrolling the answerers :)

Comment: @oleslaw thought the same

Comment: @oleslaw then please post an answer explaining the lines that gave you that idea. Maybe I'll give you (an) up...vote.

Comment: Are the no caps a hint?

Comment: @Mithrandir. somehow, but kind of a long shot. Don't focus on them. I will explain after I get an answer for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock your computer when you walk away!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/lock-your-computer-when-you-walk-away)

Comment: @Mithrandir this is certainly not a duplicate. Even if the answer is the same it's a totally different approach. You won't go around marking as duplicate all riddles that have the answer "The Sun" for example. And I owed you an explanation about the missing caps. It made everything lowercase in order not to make them stand out and make the riddle easier, not that it was very hard to begin with.

Comment: @Marius it was a joke. As you can see, I didn't VTC. I guess you just didn't catch it *shrug*

Comment: @Mithrandir. Yep. Sorry. I didn't catch it. :). But next time if you want to do it properly mark it as duplicate of [Be careful on what you click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The song in question is

> Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up

Because:
not sure if you like this
expecting to end with a kiss?

> Sounds like a love song, so it should "end with a kiss"

video? You saw it.
even shared it a bit?

> Everyone saw it :) Many also "shared" it by trying to rickroll others.

ranting on the web somewhere
going to give you a little scare

> Hides in the darkest places in teh web just waiting to attack you by an unsuspiciously looking link provided by your friend.

once it was a love song
now? Just a click gone wrong

> It is a love song, but now it is used rather for rickrolling (one wrong click) than actual listening.

not adding this verse as a prank
actually I did, I'll be frank.

> By giving a reference to this song, this can actually be seen as a(nother) prank.

give you a hint? I'm very picky
I tell you it's not sung by Martin, Ricky

> This is a song of **Rick** Astley, not **Ricky** Martin

very confused about it right now?
explanation is in here, somehow.

> The first letters of the sentences start with: nevergonnagIveyouup

young people know it.
old ones at one point enjoyed it.

> Young people know it from rickrolling, older people enjoyed listening to it when the song was young.

unable to find something wrong
unless you try sing along.
please find the name of the song.

> probably reference to some of the lyrics - as OP says - it is not a hint itself.

Comment: The last verse can be sung as if part of the song if you break up the syllables correctly, I think that was the intention.

Answer (score 6):

Is it...

> Rick Astley - Never gonna give you up?

Because:

> The first letters of the sentences read us: never gonna gIve you up

Comment: You are right, but there are other hints in there. Can you please explain some of them for a better answer?

Comment: @oleslaw did that for me now ;)

Comment: @MikeLimburg you should ask oleslaw if you can use his answers, in order to have a complete answer

Comment: I did not get all of them though :) Feel free to use my answer to upgrade yours.

Comment: @oleslaw Just updated your answer instead. Good explanations!